# What's the simplest, most concise web technology to build an app with on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, programming-languages

Now that Java has allowed multiple additional languages to run on top of Google App Engine, which of the newly available languages would allow an app to be developed the most simply and concisely? Let's assume most people are aware of Ruby on Rails, PHP, Coldfusion and Python/Django and we can take for granted that these are pretty simple and concise. **Excluding these**, which technology that is now available because of Java would surprise people to know how simple and concise it is to develop a web app in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think JAX-RS is probably the simplest and most concise for Java. Both [Jersey](http://jersey.dev.java.net) and [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org) are available for google appe engine.

Take a look here for the [supported Java frameworks](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine?version=26) in Google App Engine.

Comment: Yes, I am sure, take a look here http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine?version=26

Answer (score 1):

Google has made it very easy with their Eclipse plugin for App Engine to develop in GWT which can give web apps a very AJAXy web 2.0 feel without much effort.

Comment: I would not consider GWT very concise. #1 it's Java syntax. #2 There's a lot of wiring up of event triggers and responses because of its restfulness.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what concrete attributes you're looking for. Conciseness is all very well, until it interferes with readability. As far as simplicity goes, Java or Python are going to be the simplest options for a while, simply because they're officially supported and have fully developed APIs.

Comment: The concrete attributes I'm looking for are conciseness and simplicity. Ruby and Python are prime examples of this. I consider Ruby one of the most concise and readable languages around, with Python not far behind. Ola Bini got JRuby on Rails working on GAE. And Sinatra also works and is concise. In the Python world Massimo di Pierro has web2py running on GAE although with questionable performance - I've heard it's quite resource-intensive and causes the quotas to be exceeded for some.

Comment: You already said that, but 'conciseness' and 'simplicity' aren't really that easily summed up. Perl is more concise than Python (but much less readable!), and certain functional languages are likely to be more concise again. BrainFuck is simpler than pretty much everything.